# Width in pixels of a text/caption in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, font-size, column-width, caption

Here is my problem, I want to know actual length of the text in pixels (note that various letters have different length in some fonts). I am going to use this for better column width adjustment in DBGrid.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the  [`Canvas.TextWidth`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextWidth) and [`Canvas.TextHeight`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextHeight) functions.

Option 1, using the canvas of the control

```
WidthInPixels := Label1.Canvas.TextWidth('My Text');
```

Option 2, creating a temporary canvas (using a Tbitmap)

```
Function GetWidthText(const Text:String; Font:TFont) : Integer;
var 
  LBmp: TBitmap; 
begin
  LBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
   LBmp.Canvas.Font := Font;
   Result := LBmp.Canvas.TextWidth(Text); 
  finally
   LBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

if you have a Delphi component has a "Canvas" property, then you can use Component.Canvas.TextWidth. For example: to get the width of the text of DBGrid you can use:

```
DBGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth('Stack');
```

Here you can find complete reference about this issue:
[Length of Delphi string in pixels](http://www.festra.com/wwwboard/messages/12607.html)